# No Registered devices in parse (Push Notifications)

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I am having trouble with push notifications using Parse.com.

I can pass a message to parse, however when I try to send a message from parse I am told that I have "No Registered Devices" when in actual fact, I have several in the Dev center!

It seems the code is working fine but feel I am missing something!

Any Ideas?

Comment: When you say "Dev Center", do you mean the Parse Dashboard -> Installation Class or the iOS Dev Center? If the latter, you need to register the Installations in Parse with the device token to send push notifications.

Comment: Thanks Bjorn but I managed to get it working, Needed to press the "Test" Button before it would work!

Comment: where is the "Test" button, @Graeme?

Comment: @wallace I think he means the "Test" button on the "Quick Start" page https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#social/mobile/ios/native/new

Comment: @wallace, sorry for the long delay, been off the grid for a while. The Test Button is at the bottom of the Set up SDK area where you get the SDK install instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I fixed it:

1. Sometimes, your XCode doesn't have all the profiles.

Sync the profiles by going to `XCode > Preferences > Accounts > Your Account` and Select `Application Id` and press refresh button (See picture below).
[image]

2. Make sure your provisioning profile is ACCURATE as the picture below:

In `Target > Build Settings > Code Signing`  AND in `Project > Build Settings > Code Signing` **(Both of them)**

Specifically you need to specify Developer Profile for Code Signing Identity. And your App provisioning profile  for `Provisioning Profile`
[image]

Comment: Nice one Raja, after I had to change some details of my account I had issues with push notifications, this process helped me get to the route of the problem with provisioning profiles.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!