# Parse: No Registered Devices Error

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have set up Parse.com's Push feature as follows, but I run into an issue when I try to send push notifications:

> 1. Certificates have been set up, signed, uploaded, etc.
> 2. SDK has been imported as per the [instructions here](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push)
> 3. AppDelegate.swift has been edited to include the following:

```
 func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
    Parse.setApplicationId("MY KEY. I KNOW IT IS CORRECT", clientKey: "MY CLIENT KEY. ALSO VERIFIED TO BE CORRECT")


    let userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationType.Alert |
        UIUserNotificationType.Badge |
        UIUserNotificationType.Sound);

    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
}


func application(application: UIApplication!, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo:NSDictionary!) {

        PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)



}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    installation.saveInBackground()
}
```

However, when I try to send a push notification by selecting my app in the Parse dashboard, selecting "Push", and selecting " + Sends A Push", I get an error

> No push notifications to display yet
>   You may need to configure push notifications for your app.

Comment: Did you verify that the bundle identifier of the certificate matches the bundle identifier of the installations you have saved on parse.com?

Comment: @BjörnKaiser Yup, they match.

Comment: The error seems to indicate that the push campaign didn't actually get created on the server. Where is this error displayed?

Comment: @HectorRamos On the parse website, when I try to send a push message.

Comment: This is how I solved this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32060021/1553014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same issue, and hammered my head against the wall for a while trying to figure it out until I realized that when I went to the Push Notifications tab in Parse, it somehow switched me into another earlier app that I had set up. Make sure you have the right app selected in the upper left corner. Hopefully your solution is as simple as mine was.